# Need to generate/validate OAuth tokens in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, oauth, asp.net-core

I have built an API in C# ASP.NET 5.

This is current the code library I use to generate and validate OAUTH tokens https://github.com/mrsheepuk/ASPNETSelfCreatedTokenAuthExample

The logged in user calls my API (passing the Bearer token in the header) to retrieve their saved notes from my NoteController. In my NoteController I retrieve the userNo from the Auth token claims and retrieve the users notes from the database. If the user's Auth token is invalid then I send them back a HTTP 401.

I have added code in my Startup.cs to enable Authorization:

```
// Enable the use of an [Authorize("Bearer")] attribute on methods and classes to protect.
services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
             {
                auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
             });
```

My problem: as good as the code library (ASPNETSelfCreatedTokenAuthExample) is, it does not provide an OAuth refresh token mechanism.

I have tried to find a decent library to replace the one I am currently using.
I want a library that uses refresh tokens etc.

I have looked at IdentityServer4 but the examples are just for generating tokens in a dedicated server

I don't quite understand what to do :(

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

DONE IT!!! :D
found this amazing blog post
http://capesean.co.za/blog/asp-net-5-jwt-tokens/
It took me a few mins to get his source code to work.
I actually had to use someone's fork of the solution to get it to work
https://github.com/VoronFX/openiddict-test

My steps to get it to work:
1. Download https://github.com/VoronFX/openiddict-test

**Next steps are copied from (https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core)**

2. run these commands:

   set DNX_UNSTABLE_FEED=https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/
   dnvm upgrade -u
3. Update your project.json to import the OpenIddict package:

   "dependencies": {
       "OpenIddict": "1.0.0-*"
   },

Answer (score 0):

Direction -> If I would have such a task, probably I would get familiar with the official AspNetCore middleware and try to implement my own middleware based on the official OAuth middleware. Have a look here -> https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.

More authentication middlewares: https://github.com/aspnet/Security